# Referencing a variable to an existing array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, variable-assignment

I'm pretty new to C and starting to play with pointers. I haven't found a way to assign an array to multiple variables.
What I want ideally is:

```
char myArray[10] = "test";
char (*p)[10] = &myArray;
char anotherArray[10];
anotherArray = *p;
```

This doesn't work and I don't know why.
I have found a way to "copy" the array by using a for loop,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   anotherArray[i] = myArray[i];
}
```

I don't know if it's good practice to do it and if there is an easier way.

The array content is not supposed to change so I just want to have a simple way to do this:

```
firstArr[size] = "content";
secondArr = firstArr;
```

Comment: Do you want each variable to reference the same array/memory or do you want multiple copies of the same array? That is, if the array contents are changed via one variable do you want the same change to be seen by all variables?

Comment: What is `input`? Why the strange parenthesis around `(*p)`?

Comment: @MM1 Use standard C function strcpy to copy a string from one character array to another.

Comment: Sorry, edited it just now

Comment: Still not very clear. But it seems you want this: `char firstArr[size] = "content"; char *secondArr = firstArr;`?

Comment: I want secondArr to be also "content"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't assign arrays in C, neither by itself nor by dereferencing pointers to arrays, the syntax simply doesn't allow it.

Arrays are normally copied with `memcpy`. In case they are strings, you can also use `strcpy`, which copies up until it finds the string null terminator.

In your example, this would be `strcpy(anotherArray, *p);`. But to use an array pointer of type `char (*)[10]` is a bit weird practice, it is far more common to use a pointer to the first element of the array. I would recommend that you change your code to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
  char input[10] = "test";
  char* p = input;
  char anotherArray[10];

  strcpy(anotherArray, p);
  puts(anotherArray);
}
```

Comment: Since the array‘s are always the same size, I‘d still use memcpy

Comment: I added contextual phrase, because the OP explicitly attempts to do it by dereferencing a pointer to an array in the first example, because the answer is good beside. +1 Feel free to roll the edit back pr change it if you don´t like it.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio That's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign an array to multiple variables, but you can assign multiple variables to point to an array.

Pointers are all about memory and the memory that they **point** to.

Statements such as this assign a fixed amount of memory (10 `char` sized bytes of memory) to the variable `myArray` and initialises the contents to contain "test1".

`char myArray[10] = "test1";`

By definition `myArray` is actually a pointer to the first memory location, which in this case holds a char of value `'t'`, but it is fixed to that memory.

You can define another pointer to type char and assign it the same value as the pointer to the memory that holds the data `"test1"` - thus:

```
char *secondPtr = myArray;
```

Now `secondPtr` and `myArray` both point to the same memory, which contains `"test1"`. There aren't two copies of the data, but it may appear so if you did

```
printf("myArray %s", myArray);
printf("secondPtr %s", secondPtr);
```

Now you can use either `myArray` or `secondPtr` to alter the same data, which is why pointers should be treated with care.

Now as secondPtr is just a pointer to a char and as such it isn't fixed in the same way that myArray is, so you can do this:

```
char myArray2[10] = "test2";
secondPtr = myArray;
printf("secondPtr %s", secondPtr);

secondPtr = myArray2;
printf("secondPtr %s", secondPtr);
```

To copy data from one array to another you can use memcpy, which will copy a specified number of bytes(octets) of memory from one location to another.

The same process is performed by a loop (this is basic code, but not really the best way of performing it as there are no checks on the size of the arrays nor on the number of loop iterations)e.g.

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
  myArray2[i] = myArray[i];
}
```

this can also be:

```
secondPtr = myArray2;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
  myArray2[i] = secondPtr +i;
}
```